# Como inserir linha na parte de cima de uma tabela usando JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Uso o código abaixo pra inserir uma linha em uma tabela:

```
var linha = "<tr>";
linha += '<td class="cnes">' + cnes + '</td>';
linha += '<td class="cbo">' + cbo + '</td>';
linha += '<td class="profissional">' + profissional + '</td>';
linha += '<td class="procedimento">' + procedimento + '</td>';
linha += '<td class="idade">' + idade + '</td>';
linha += '<td class="quant">' + quant + '</td>';
linha += '<td><button class="btn btn-danger" style="text-align:center;" onclick="remove(this)">Excluir</button></td>'
linha += '</tr>';

$("#tabelaProducao").append(linha);
```

Sendo que ele insere no final da mesma e eu preciso que seja inserida na segunda linha (a primeira é o cabeçalho das colunas). Como faço?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao invés do `append` use o `prepend` e coloque um `tbody` para separar cabeçalho do corpo:

```
...
$("#tabelaProducao tbody").prepend(linha);
```

**Exemplo**

```js
var linha = "<tr>";
linha += '<td class="cnes"> Item' + 3 + '</td>';
linha += '<td class="cbo"> Item' + 4 + '</td>';
linha += '</tr>';

$("#tabelaProducao tbody").prepend(linha);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabelaProducao">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Titulo 1</th>
      <th>Titulo 2</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo de onde eu devo incluir o `tbody` geralmente crio as tabelas sem ele?

Comment: Sim @ItaloRodrigo, atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Lembro que já usei a [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).

```
var linha = "<tr>";
linha += '<td class="cnes">' + cnes + '</td>';
linha += '<td class="cbo">' + cbo + '</td>';
linha += '<td class="profissional">' + profissional + '</td>';
linha += '<td class="procedimento">' + procedimento + '</td>';
linha += '<td class="idade">' + idade + '</td>';
linha += '<td class="quant">' + quant + '</td>';
linha += '<td><button class="btn btn-danger" style="text-align:center;" onclick="remove(this)">Excluir</button></td>'
linha += '</tr>';

$("#tabelaProducao").insertBefore(linha);
```

Dei uma pesquisada e achei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353736/4551469) que tem mais duas opções.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("table > tbody").prepend("<tr><td>Linha Nova 1</td><td>Linha Nova 2</td><td>Linha Nova 3</td>   </tr>")
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Coluna 1</th>
      <th>Coluna 2</th>
      <th>Coluna 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Linha 1</td>
      <td>Linha 2</td>
      <td>Linha 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Exatamente, rs, é que copiei o código do thead! uhauhauahuahu, Malsssss